# OPEN GL ES 2.0 - glGetAttribLocation returning -1 when using normals

Tags: android, opengl-es

My code:

```
public void draw1(float[] mvpMatrix) {
    // Add program to OpenGL environment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

    mNormalHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "a_normal");//new line

    fsTexture = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "Texture");
    vsTextureCoord = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "texCoord");
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(fsTexture, 0);

    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");
    // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
            mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            vertexStride, vertexBuffer);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vsTextureCoord, COORDS_PER_TEXTURE,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            TextureStride, texBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vsTextureCoord);

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mNormalHandle, COORDS_PER_NORMAL, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            12, normalbuffer);//new line

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mNormalHandle);//new line


    // Draw the triangle
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, tablelamp21NumVerts);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(vsTextureCoord);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mNormalHandle);//new line
}
```

so i am getting a glGetUniformLocation: glError 1281 at         MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation"); code line 
after debugging i found that my mNormalHandle is -1 i.e         GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "a_normal"); is returning -1, even though i using it in the vertex shader and i am using GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(mProgram, 2, "a_normal"); before linking please help.
shaders code:

```
   private final String vertexShaderCode =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                "uniform mat4 u_MVMatrix;" +

                "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                "attribute vec2 texCoord;" +
                "attribute vec3 a_normal;"+ //new line

                "varying vec3 v_normal;"+//new line
                "varying vec2 texCoordOut;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "   v_normal = vec3(u_MVMatrix * vec4(a_normal, 0.0));"+
                "   texCoordOut = texCoord;" +
                "   gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform sampler2D Texture;" +
                "varying vec2 texCoordOut;"+
                "void main() {" +
                " gl_FragColor = texture2D(Texture, texCoordOut);" +
                "}";
```

Comment: You are trying to get `uMVPMatrix` and your shader has `u_MVMatrix`.

Comment: i changed u_MVMatrix with uMVPMatrix still i am getting the error , so what exactly is happening , after executing i am getting the 3D model but when i am touching the screen i am getting the above error , so to rectify that i tried debugging then i found that my mNormalHandle is -1.

Comment: `a_normal ` is a vertex attribute (not a uniform variable).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer to an outdated question, but if that can help other developers: I think the GLSL compiler is pretty good to strip unused variables.

For example, with the follow vertex and fragment shader compiled with the OpenGL/ES driver of an Android emulator:

```
private val vertexShaderCode = """attribute vec4 in_position;
            attribute vec2 in_texcoord;

            uniform mat4 projection;
            uniform mat4 view;
            uniform mat4 model;

            varying vec2 var_texcoord;

            void main() {
                var_texcoord = in_texcoord;
                gl_Position = projection * view * model * in_position;
            }
            """

    private val fragmentShaderCode = """
            precision mediump float;

            varying vec2 var_texcoord;

            uniform sampler2D texture;
            uniform vec4 color;

            void main() {
                gl_FragColor = color;
            }
            """
```

GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "in_texcoord"); will return -1

Now if we use var_texcoord to compute the color in the fragment shader:

```
private val fragmentShaderCode = """
            precision mediump float;

            varying vec2 var_texcoord;

            uniform sampler2D texture;
            uniform vec4 color;

            void main() {
                gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, var_texcoord);
            }
            """
```

GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "in_texcoord"); will return a valid id, > -1

Apparently the GLSL compiler can strip variable and varying variable, if they are not used, so it's seems possible that your a_normal variable is removed too.