# shader not getting compiled in Chrome OS, openglES 3.0

Tags: c++, shader, emscripten, opengl-es-3.0

i have an app built using webgl support of emscripten, the app runs perfectly find in windows, linux and macOS, but for some reason its giving error in line 3 chrome OS.

```
1: function _glEnableVertexAttribArray(index) {
2:  var cb = GL.currentContext.clientBuffers[index];
3:  cb.enabled = true;
4:  GLctx.enableVertexAttribArray(index);
5: }
```

on debugging i found that the value of index is -1 at the time of error.

so i am guessing there is some issue with my shader program.

below is one sample vertex shader i am using.

```
R"glsl(
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 vertex_normal;
layout (location = 3) in vec2 uv;

out vec3 oFragPosition;
out vec3 oNormal;
out vec2 oUV;
out vec3 overtexNormal;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

out float flogz;

void main()
{
   oFragPosition = vec3(model * vec4(position, 1.0f));
   oNormal = (model * vec4(normal, 1.0)).xyz;
   vec4 t = vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
   t = model * t;
   oNormal.x = oNormal.x - t.x;
   oNormal.y = oNormal.y - t.y;
   oNormal.z = oNormal.z - t.z;
   oNormal = normalize(oNormal);
   oUV = uv;
   overtexNormal = vertex_normal;

   gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0);
}

)glsl"
```

in my system the chrome://gpu gave the following gpu configuration:
[GPU config chrome os](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0osYd.png)

as you can see, it has openglES 3.2.
and pixel and fragment shader version 3.2

in code i am asking to make a opengles 3.0 context.
also my shader version is 300 es. is the error is due the version mismatch?

or what could be the issue here?

**EDIT:**
i checked my linux system, its also has the same configuration openGL ES 3.20 and  glsl version is 3.20.

Comment: In a web assembly, you can only use OpenGL ES 3.0, but not OpenGL ES 3.2. (OpenGL ES 3.0 is mapped to the corresponding features of WebGL 2.0)

Comment: sorry if this is an obvious doubt, but here the opengles version is 3.2 but in code i am querying for version 3.0. i am guess that 3.2 is the max supported version by the system, hence 3.0 should also be supported. or am i wrong here??

should the gpu version has to be exactly 3.0 or any higher version that 3.0 will work??

Comment: No. I just wanted to point out that you can only use features that are supported by WebGL 2.0. Anyway, you say "shader not getting compiled". What is the shader compile error message?

Comment: The error is not caused by the shader, but by `glEnableVertexAttribArray`

Comment: its not throwing any error. i assumed that bacause index value is -1 at the time of error, meaning the location does not exists, so there might be issue with my shader program.

Comment: I can't see any problem in the vertex shader. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

apparently https://stackoverflow.com/a/45154357/13407557 helped,

my overtexNormal attribute was not used anywhere in fragment shader and hence it was stripped from my shader program after compilation, so upon querying for the location of the attribute it returned -1, this was causing glEnableVertexAttribArray to fail.